# Calculate the outer vertices for a border of uniform thickness x drawn around a polygon

Tags: android, opengl-es, border, polygon, vertex

I have a polygon defined by a center point C and an array of outer vertices (V<sub>0</sub>, V<sub>1</sub>, .., V<sub>n</sub>) entered in CCW order. For every vertex V<sub>i</sub>, I know the angle formed by vertices V<sub>(i-1)%n</sub>, V<sub>i</sub>, and V<sub>(i+1)%n</sub>, and I can normalize the vector from C to V<sub>i</sub>. I can also translate a vertex by any given vector. The outer vertices of my polygon can serve as the inner vertices of my border, so I just need to know how to calculate the outer vertices of the border.

Here's what I tried:

```js
public static Vertex[] calculateOuterVerticesForBorder(Polygon polygon, float borderThickness) {

  int outerVertexCount = polygon.outerVertexCount;

  Vertex[] bOuterVertices = new Vertex[outerVertexCount];

  for (int i = 0; i < outerVertexCount; i++) {
    Vertex pOuterVertex = polygon.outerVertices[i];
    float pOuterVertexAngle = polygon.outerVertexAngles[i];
    Vector pVectorNorm = new Vector(polygon.center, pOuterVertex).toLength(borderThickness);
    //Here I should probably make some adjustment to pVectorNorm based on the 
    //outer vertex angle, or perhaps the angle from C to Vi to V(i+1)
    Vertex bOuterVertex = new Translation(vectorNorm).transform(pOuterVertex);
    bOuterVertices[i] = bOuterVertex;
  }

  return bOuterVertices;
}
```

Problem is, this calculation results in a border that does not have uniform thickness, as you can see in the image below:

[Image of non-uniform border drawn around some of my polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGOPG.png)

Comment: Have you tried using a shader to construct the border instead of calculating on the client?

Comment: No, I assumed it would be more efficient to calculate the border vertices on the client so that I can save the result in my database for reuse.

Comment: I also need to be able to access the border vertices for a contains(vertex) method that I use to check if a point lies inside the border.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is calculate a halfway angle between the two lines that join at the vertex. Then you extend the border `borderThickness` distance along that angle vector, and then add that point to the list comprising the "border" polygon.

I'd propose code that kinda looks like this:

```
//This math is weird, but it basically just returns a boolean value: 
//are these three points convex or concave, using counterclockwise ordering?
boolean isConvex(Vertex previousVertex, Vertex currentVertex, Vertex nextVertex) {
    return
        (
        previousVertex.x * (nextVertex.y - currentVertex.y) +
        currentVertex.x * (previousVertex.y - nextVertex.y) +
        nextVertex.x * (currentVertex.y - previousVertex.y)
        ) < 0;
}

Vertex getBorderVertex(Vertex previousVertex, Vertex currentVertex, Vertex nextVertex, float borderDistance) {
    //I'm using the word "vector" here to distinguish numbers which are directions, 
    //whereas "vertex" refers to a point. Mathematically, there's no difference.
    Vector line1 = Vector(currentVertex.x - previousVertex.x, currentVertex.y - previousVertex.y);
    //normalize == make the length equal to 1
    line1 = normalize(line1);
    Vector line2 = Vector(currentVertex.x - nextVertex.x, currentVertex.y - nextVertex.y);
    line2 = normalize(line2);

    //We really shouldn't have joints that are just straight lines 
    //(especially because floating point numbers are imprecise), 
    //but we want the formula to be generic enough to handle this edge case (pun intended)

    //The Dot Product is the same as the dot product algorithm you learned in primary school geometry.
    float dotProduct = line1.dot(line2);
    if(dotProduct == 1 || dotProduct == -1) {
        Vector normalVector = Vector(line1.y, -line1.x);
        normalVector = normalVector.multiply(borderDistance);
        return Vertex(currentVertex.x + normalVector.x, currentVertex.y + normalVector.y);
    }
    Vector halfwayLine = line1.plus(line2);

    //We want the algorithm to work correctly regardless of whether it's a concave joint 
    //or a convex joint. If it's concave, we need to reverse the direction.
    if(!isConvex(previousVertex, currentVertex, nextVertex)) 
        halfwayLine = halfwayLine.multiply(-1);

    halfwayLine = normalize(halfwayLine);
    halfwayLine = halfwayLine.multiply(borderDistance);
    return Vertex(currentVertex.x + halfwayLine.x, currentVertex.y, halfwayLine.y);
}
```

And then all this code can be invoked by your program like so:

```
for(int vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < outerVertexCount; vertexIndex++) {
    //The weird math here is only because modulos of negative values can 
    //return negative numbers in some programming languages. If you know for certain 
    //that the modulo function will only return positive numbers, then you can remove 
    //the addition of outerVertexCount to the previousVertex index.
    Vertex previousVertex = polygon.outerVertices[(vertexIndex + outerVertexCount - 1) % outerVertexCount];
    Vertex currentVertex = polygon.outerVertices[vertexIndex];
    Vertex nextVertex = polygon.outerVertices[(vertexIndex + 1) % outerVertexCount];

    bOuterVertices[vertexIndex] = getBorderVertex(previousVertex, currentVertex, nextVertex, borderThickness);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to find a solution using your idea about the two lines joining at the vertex, but your code didn't work for me out of the box. Did you really mean to do Vector(currentVertex.y - previousVertex.y, currentVertex.x - previousVertex.x) and not Vector(currentVertex.x - previousVertex.x, currentVertex.y - previousVertex.y)? I'm assuming the vector constructor is Vector(x,y).

Comment: @William I did not. Good catch. The Normal Vector I created *is* supposed to be in that order though. The two line vectors were not.